# Prove that if {v1, v2} is a basis for sp(v1, v2), then...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that if {v1, v2} is a basis for sp(v1, v2), then

a) {v1 + v2, v1 - v2} is also a basis.

b) {v1 + v2, v1 - v2, 2v1 - 3v2} is not a basis.

a)

First, prove that sp(v1, v2) = sp(v1 + v2, v1 - v2).

Let vj be a vector in sp(v1, v2), and vj = rv1 + sv2 = [(r+s)/2](v1 + v2) + [(r-s)/2](v1 - v2), which in turn, is a vector in sp(v1 + v2, v1 - v2).

Then, since {v1 + v2, v1 - v2} is a basis for sp(v1 + v2, v1 - v2), which mutually contains sp(v1, v2), {v1 + v2, v1 - v2} is also a basis for sp(v1, v2).

b)

I can't figure out why the subset is NOT a basis, since sp(v1 + v2, v1 - v2, 2v1 - 3v2) = sp(v1, v2)?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Not only must a basis span the desired set, it must also be linearly independent.  For (b), although the span is the same, the three vectors are not linearly independent.  Make sure you understand why they aren't.  Do you remember the definition of linear independence of a set of vectors?

Comment: You should take the time to prove it from first principles, but as a shortcut once you have had more practice and don't need to waste time on routine problems, there is a useful theorem that a vector space with a basis consisting of $n$ vectors is called "$n$-dimensional" and for any $n$-dimensional vector space, any and all choices of bases will consist of exactly $n$ vectors.  Since $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is a basis for $sp(v_1,v_2)$ we know it is two-dimensional.  Since $\{v_1+v_2,v_1-v_2,2v_1-3v_3\}$ has more than two vectors, we know it could not be a basis.

Comment: Welcome again to Math.Stackexchange.  I applaud you on showing your work and thought process on the problem.  This is a model example of how a question should be asked here in terms of showing work, title choice, and tag selection.  +1.  An unfortunately large number of new users miss doing this entirely, so it is refreshing to see. There are some ways in which it can still be improved. Consider visiting [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to typeset equations with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ to make it easier to read.

Comment: Hi thanks for the encouragement, I'll make some improvement next time I post. And thank you as well for the reminder of linear independence, it is very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-\frac{1}{2}(v_1+v_2)+\frac{5}{2}(v_1-v_2)=2v_1-3v_2$$

Comment: Succint, yet sufficient